# Why is my Anylogic Simulation stopping before all agents run the simulation?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm currently writing my master thesis and whilst doing that I'm being forced to use Anylogic for a simulation. This is my first time creating a simulation model or doing something remotely similar to that. I'm a complete beginner unfortunatly and time is beginning to run out for my thesis. The simulation is surpposed to show the waittime and stock of cars at a harbour.
The simulation model I created looks like picture 1:
[Simulation Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDTQT.png)

The data for the simulation comes from a real company and exists in an excel-sheet.
I can successfully create a model in anylogic and also run that model, however the simulation never runs till the end, but rather stops after the last car enters the simulation, not the last ship exits it. This means, that a significant portion of cars never acually runs the simulation.
This error always appears. [Error code after simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCeYB.png)

As far as I'm aware I've set the stop date for the simulation long after the end of the last ship's transport. Does anybody know why the simulation stops before?

I really need some help and my supervisor sadly doesn't know Anylogic too well either.

EDIT: Hopefully this helps with understanding the data set und properties of the source block

[Properties of the source block Fahrzeuge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9a3A.png)

[Data type for the arrival date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjuZY.png)

EDIT 2:

I'm sorry that was the wrong screeshot.
[Properties Source Fahrzeug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SsF6.png)

I have just tried to run the simulation with just the first 10 cars and that works, so I think there might be an error in the data somewhere, that causes the simulation to fail. I will now try and add more and more cars until the simulation fails, so I can hopefully narrow the row with the error down.

Comment: As per the comments below the error is likely in row 18925, column "actual_transport_endx..." check your DB values in AnyLogic

Answer (score 1):

Your simulation is stopping due to the error. And the error is specifying that you don't have a date for one of your data entries.

Given the little information provided I assume that you have set up your source to generate agents from the database and that you have imported your Excel sheet into the database.

Double-check that all your entries have an Arrival date.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!
Unfortunately that was the first thing I checked as well, as I interpreted the error message the same. Every car has a start and arrival date and there doesn't seem to be an error in the data set. Is it possible, that there is a mistake in Anylogic I made, that would have this as a consequence?

Comment: Please provide more detail about your source block called `Fahrzeuge`? I will be really surprised if the date value or format is not the issue...  are you sure in your DB the values are correct? Count the number of agents created at `Fahrzeuge` and then you will see which is the problem, i.e. if 500 was created then line 501 in your DB is the problem. Make sure it has a date value in the correct format.

Comment: The data type for the column with the arrival date in Anylogic is set to "date", which I believe is correct. In Excel the data typ is a custom form of date, can that be the problem?  The Simulation only stops after 18.924 cars are spawned. The Excel dataset consists of 19.825 cars. However the data seems complete to me, there are no empty or dissimilar fields compared to all the other rows.

Comment: The new screenshot you added is of Main, not the source block… please go to the DB and check the data in Row 18925